# How can I use set operations to delete objects in an entitycollection that match a collection of view models?

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, linq-to-objects, entitycollection

Here is a very basic example of what I want to do. The code I have come up with seems quite verbose... ie looping through the collection, etc.

I am using a Telerik MVC grid that posts back a collection of deleted, inserted and updated ViewModels. The view models are similar but not exactly the same as the entity.

For example... I have:

Order.Lines. Lines is an entity collection (navigation property) containing OrderDetail records. In the update action of my controller using the I have a List names DeletedLines pulled from the POST data. I also have queried the database and have the Order entity including the Lines collection.

Now I basically want to tell it to delete all the OrderDetails in the Lines EntityCollection.

The way I have done it is something like:

```
foreach (var line in DeletedLines) {
   db.DeleteObject(Order.Lines.Where(l => l.Key == line.Key).SingleOrDefault())
}
```

I was hoping there was a way that I could use .Interset() to get a collection of entities to delete and pass that to DeleteObject.. however, DeleteObject seems to only accept a single entity rather than a collection.

Perhaps the above is good enough.. but it seemed like there should be an easier method.

Thanks,
BOb

Comment: FWIW, you can add a simple extension method to delete more than one at a time, but it would just do a foreach :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the items in DeletedLines attached to the context? If so, what about this?

```
foreach (var line in DeletedLines) db.DeleteObject(line);
```

**Response to comment #1**

Ok, I see now. You can make your code a bit shorter, but not much:

```
foreach (var line in DeletedLines) {
   db.DeleteObject(Order.Lines.SingleOrDefault(l => l.Key == line.Key))
}
```

I'm not sure if DeleteObject will throw an exception when you pass it null. If it does, you may be even better off using Single, as long as you're sure the item is in there:

```
foreach (var line in DeletedLines) {
   db.DeleteObject(Order.Lines.Single(l => l.Key == line.Key))
}
```

Comment: No.. DeletedLines is a collection of ViewModels... so they are not in the context.

Comment: Thanks. While passing the Lambda is a bit more concise I guess there isn't really a way to use the linq SetOperations for this. At least that I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to re-query the database and either already have the mapping table PK values (or can include them in the client call), you could use one of Alex James's tips for deleting without first retrieving:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/03/27/tip-9-deleting-an-object-without-retrieving-it.aspx